# Merging Excel cells using Xlsxwriter in Python

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I want to merge several series of cell ranges in an Excel file using Python Xlsxwriter, I found the Python command in the Xlsxwriter documentation in this website
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_merge1.html
 as below:

```
worksheet.merge_range('B4:D4')
```

The only problem is that I have my ranges in row and columns numbers format for example (0,0) which is equal to A1. But Xlsxwriter seems to only accept format like A1. I was wondering if anybody else had the same problem and if there is any solution for that.

Comment: See http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/worksheet.html#merge_range and http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_cell_notation.html#cell-notation

Comment: both these pages dont exist

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Almost all methods in XlsxWriter support both `A1` and `(row, col)` notation, [see the docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html). So the following are equivalent for [`merge_range()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-merge-range):

```
worksheet.merge_range('B4:D4',    'Merged Range', merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range(3, 1, 3, 3, 'Merged Range', merge_format)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and  great package. I have been reading the documentation to also find a way to change cell sizes using Xlsxwriter but i just could find the way to change font size not cell size, could you also tell me which documentation page should i refer to?

Comment: found it, set_row() and set_column() should be used